# HttpResponse differs in Android and Java

Tags: java, android, httpurlconnection, apache-httpclient-4.x

I am looking for some help!
I have some code doing server auth and retrieving the response from server. When i execute it in eclipse in my java project I've got reddirrect response like :

```
<html><head><meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0;url=SiteIamLoggingPageURL/"/></head></html>
```

But when i am excecuting the same code in my android app, ive got response equal to the failed login scenario.

```
HttpPost post = new HttpPost(loginPageAdress);
List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
//nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("remember", "1"));
nameValuePairs
        .add(new BasicNameValuePair("email", "email"));
nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("password", "password"));

post.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs, "utf-8"));
StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();

HttpResponse response = client.execute(post, httpContext);
BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(response
        .getEntity().getContent(), "UTF-8"));
String line = "";
while ((line = rd.readLine()) != null) {
    stringBuilder.append(line).append("\n");
}
System.out.println(stringBuilder.toString());
```

What is the problem? o.o Thank you for your time!

Comment: What's the logcat say? Maybe you forgot to put INTERNET permission into AndroidManifest.xml

Comment: There are no logCat errors or so, and i havent forgot about INTERNET permission :<

Comment: What it the value of `response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();` Your authentication code doesn't look quite right to me. The response status code will tell some basic information about the authentication type server used for login.

Answer (score 0):

Sound like you forgot adding

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

in AndroidManifest.xml.
Have a look at [this tutorial](http://sarangasl.blogspot.com/2011/06/android-login-screen-using-httpclient.html)

Comment: I really havent forgot about that :) I am getting the response HTML-page so my connection is OK. There must be another thing ~_~

Answer (score 0):

1. if this is your Authentication code you must use Redirection via Headers not via HTML refresh metatag. Server should issue Location: http:/authenticated.jsp f.e.
2. To check whats really going on use Wireshark. Then you not blind anymore. Here - request from Android here answer from server. It is very useful tool spend some time with it.

Answer (score 0):

It could be because your not executing the HTTP request on a separate `Thread`. Read more about this here:

### [Why Ice Cream Sandwich Crashes Your App](http://www.androiddesignpatterns.com/2012/06/app-force-close-honeycomb-ics.html)

Comment: In fact this is running in another thread :S Broken my brain already. Maybe there are some differences in my Java HttpClient 4.2 and that one android has...

Comment: Yeah, well the java HttpClient isn't thread safe, IIRC... or am I wrong? The `AndroidHttpClient` is thread safe, so perhaps you should try using that instead (introduced in Froyo, Android 2.2 I believe).